# Division to percentage in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, division

If

`@prescribed_wod_count = @user.workouts.rx_workouts.count` returns `4`

and

`@user_workout_count = @user.workouts.count` returns `26`

how come

`<%= number_to_percentage(@prescribed_wod_count / @user_workout_count) %>` returns `0.000%` and not 15% ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It does integer division, before you call number_to_percentage.

You want

```
<%= number_to_percentage(@prescribed_wod_count.to_f / @user_workout_count) %>
```

to force it to do floating-point

Comment: This would return `0.154%`, not the `15%` described in the question. It would be necessary to multiply by 100 as well to get that.